# Laplace interpolation between known values in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, heatmap

I'm working on a heatmap generation program which hopefully will fill in the colors based on value samples provided from a building layout (this is not GPS based).

If I have only a few known data points such as these in a large matrix of unknowns, how do I get the values in between interpolated in Python?:

```
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,9
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0
```

I understand that bilinear won't do it, and Gaussian will bring all the peaks down to low values due to the sheer number of surrounding zeros.  This is obviously a matrix handling proposition, and I don't need it to be Bezier curve smooth, just close enough to be a graphic representation would be fine. My matrix will end up being about 1500×900 cells in size, with approximately 100 known points.

Once the values are interpolated, I have written code to convert it all to colors, no problem. It's just that right now I'm getting single colored pixels sprinkled over a black background.

Comment: What is the context of your app? Are you able to bring a library like SciPy into the app?

Comment: I believe Scipy's interp2d (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) might solve your problem, unfortunately, I can't test it right now, so I won't post this as an answer, but take a look

Comment: Yes, it looks like interp2D is EXACTLY what I need.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Proposing a naive solution:

Step 1: interpolate and extrapolate existing data points onto surroundings.
This can be done using "wave propagation" type algorithm.
The known points "spread out" their values onto surroundings until all the grid is "flooded" with some known values. At the end of this stage you have a number of intersected "disks", and no zeroes left.

Step 2: smoothen the result (using [bilinear filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering) or some other filtering).

If you are able to use ScyPy, then [interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) does exactly what you want. A possible problem with is that it seems to not extrapolate smoothly [according to this issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8099). This means that all values near the walls are going to be the same as closest their neighbour points. This can be solved by putting thermometers in all 4 corners :)

Comment: Yes, it looks like interp2D is EXACTLY what I need.  Thanks very much.